# Django Queryset how to create such a query?

Tags: python, django

There are two tables
Products and Price history
It is necessary to display the latest price by date from the price history table.
It will work on Sqlite, but I can't figure out how to do it through Queryset

```
SELECT name,max(date),price,price_discount FROM polls_products
INNER JOIN polls_history_price on polls_history_price.product_id = polls_products.id
GROUP BY polls_products.id


class Products(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    date_create = models.DateTimeField('Event Date')

class HistoryPrice(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='price_list')
    date = models.DateTimeField('Event Date')
    price = models.FloatField(blank=True,)
    price_discount = models.FloatField(blank=False)
```

trying to get so

```
Products.objects.prefetch_related('price_list').values('name','price_list__product_id').annotate(price_date=Max('price_list__date'))
```

only need to add the "price" field

Comment: Do you mean that you want to get latest related `HistoryPrice` (and its fields) to `Products`?

Comment: yes
Products.objects.prefetch_related('price_list').values('name','price_list__product_id').annotate(price_date=Max('price_list__date'))
only need to add the "price" field

Comment: Nice query you got there. My answer might help you finish it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want get `QuerySet`, you can get objects only of one model. But you can easily access values that you need. To get latest related `HistoryPrice` (by date, not id) you can add a simple function to `Products` model:

```
class Products(models.Model):
    ...

    def get_latest_history_price(self):
        return self.price_list.order_by('date').last()    # get object

    def get_latest_history_price_price(self):
        return self.price_list.order_by('date').last().price   # get price
```

That will help you easily get `HistoryPrice` object for current `Products` object, like that:

```
products = Products.objects.first()           # get an object of Products model
price = products.get_latest_history_price()   # get the newest related HistoryPrice object
price.price                                   # get price field value of HistoryPrice object
price.price_discount                          # get price_discount field value of HistoryPrice object
```

Comment: this approach will create queries for each product separate queries

Comment: Oh, yes. I suppose for clean QuerySet this will not help, cause you cannot call function inside `values()` method. I think you may try this with function: `[{'name': p.name, 'price': p.get_latest_history_price_price(), 'product id': p.id, 'date': p.get_latest_history_price().date} for p in Products.objects.all()]`. Although, it will not be `QuerySet` object, but a list of dictionaries.